# Getting RewriteCond directory flag to work without trailing slash

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to detect existing directories, supporting both with and without a trailing slash in the URL but without doing a redirect for missing slashes. Here are the rules:

```
  RewriteCond /home/user/public_html%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ /home/user/public_html%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
  RewriteCond /home/user/public_html%{REQUEST_URI}/ -d
  RewriteRule ^ /home/user/public_html%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]
```

The first rule works fine when the URL contains a trailing slash, but the second rule doesn't work for no trailing slash (e.g. /foobar/ works but /foobar doesn't).

How can I set this up without doing a 30x redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use both rules at the same time, like this:

```
# Rewrite sites with trailing slash this way...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\/$
RewriteCond /home/user/public_html%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ /home/user/public_html%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# Rewrite sites without trailing slash this way...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*[^\/]$
RewriteCond /home/user/public_html%{REQUEST_URI}/ -d
RewriteRule ^ /home/user/public_html%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]
```

Those regexps are from my head and have not been tested.  And I haven't had my coffee yet.

Comment: I don't see how this differs in it's behaviour from my original solution, it just adds a check for trailing slash first so the -d check won't be executed if URI isn't matched (as opposed to mine were they would always both be executed). Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Your first rule only does "If this is a directory, then do this."  On most systems, /path/to/my/webroot/subdir and /path/to/my/webroot/subdir/ are directories.  Therefor, it's likely to always hit your first rule and never hit your second rule.

Comment: I think I understand, you mean the first RewriteCond was matching but the RewriteRule didn't function correctly? Either way, I found reversing the rules worked fine which I think basically does the same thing.